# Обновление игрового поля Игры в жизнь (Game of Life) Python. Как обновлять игровое поле за раз, не последовательно?

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, разработка-игр, pygame

Ознакомление с Игрой в Жизнь - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0_%C2%AB%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C%C2%BB.
Проблема моего кода в функции get_next_gen(). Игровое поле (Клетки) обновляется последовательно и из-за этого правила не могут корректно работать, так как изменение одной клетки напрямую влияет на клетку идущую за ней. Функция должна принимать на вход массив из всех клеток и обновлять все клетки РАЗОМ. "Важно помнить, что обновление всего поля должно происходить за один раз, если состояние клеток менять последовательно, то это повлияет на результат игры".

```
import pygame as pg

# Константы
black = pg.Color(0, 0, 0)
dead = pg.Color(70, 33, 26)
alive = pg.Color(186, 85, 54)
rules = {'born': [3],
         'survive': [2, 3]}
fps = 100
size = w, h = 900, 600
scr = pg.display.set_mode(size)
pg.display.set_caption('Cell Machine')
cell_size = 20


# Класс клеточки
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, size: int, life: bool = False) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.rect = x, y, size, size
        self.life = life

    # Использовал этот метод для обработки нажатия ЛКМ
    def is_pressed(self, pos) -> bool:
        x, y = pos
        if self.x < x < self.x + self.size and self.y < y < self.y + self.size:
            return True

    #Изменение состояния клетки
    def change(self) -> None:
        self.life = not self.life

    #Прорисовываем клетку
    def render(self, scr: pg.Surface) -> None:
        if self.life:
            pg.draw.rect(scr, alive, self.rect)
        else:
            pg.draw.rect(scr, dead, self.rect)


# Функция подсчёта живых соседей
def get_nei(tar: Cell, cells: list) -> int:
    count = 0
    for cell in cells:
        if cell.life:
            x_sym = abs(tar.x - cell.x)
            y_sym = abs(tar.y - cell.y)

            # Горизонтальное, вертикальное или диагональное соседство
            h_nei = x_sym == 20 and tar.y == cell.y and cell.life
            v_nei = y_sym == 20 and tar.x == cell.x and cell.life
            d_nei = x_sym == 20 and y_sym == 20 and cell.life
            if h_nei or v_nei or d_nei:
                count += 1
    return count


# Просто рендер живых клеток
def update(scr: pg.Surface, cells: list) -> None:
    for cell in cells:
        cell.render(scr)


# ФУНКЦИЯ КОТОРУЮ НУЖНО ПЕРЕПИСАТЬ. ОБНОВЛЯЕТ ИГРОВОЕ ПОЛЕ
def get_next_gen(cells: list) -> None:
    create = []
    delete = []
    for cell in cells:
        neibs = get_nei(cell, cells)
        if cell.life:
            if neibs not in rules['survive']:
                cell.change()
        else:
            if neibs in rules['born']:
                cell.change()



# Главная функция
def main() -> None:
    pg.init()
    cells = []
    for x in range(0, w, cell_size):
        for y in range(0, h, cell_size):
            cells.append(Cell(x, y, cell_size))
    pause = True
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False
            # По нажанию на ЛКМ клетка должна менять своё состояние
            # Живая / мёртвая
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    # react(event.pos)
                    for cell in cells:
                        if cell.is_pressed(event.pos):
                            print(get_nei(cell, cells))
                            cell.change()


            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    pause = not pause

        # Попытка реализоваться паузу
        if not pause:
            get_next_gen(cells)
            pg.display.set_caption('PLAY')
            clock.tick(fps)
        else:
            pg.display.set_caption('PAUSE')

        #scr.fill(DEAD)
        update(scr, cells)

        pg.display.flip()
    pg.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы расчёт был правильный, нужно:

- сделать копию игрового поля
- считать, нужно ли вносить изменения, опираясь на эту копию
- применять изменения на оригинале поля

Делать копию нужно с помощью `copy.deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy

cells_copy = deepcopy(cells)
```

Но тут придётся ещё подумать, как сопоставить оригинал и копию. Обычно всё-таки делают просто сразу поле как объект, а не каждую ячейку как объект. Придётся придумать, как брать ячейку по координатам или что-то такое. Ну или переделать концепцию.

Как вариант - можно хранить дополнительное состояние в каждой ячейке и "фиксировать" его по какой-то дополнительной команде. Возможно, в вашей объектной модели так будет проще.

P.S. Всегда, когда вижу сокращённые названия функций вроде `get_nei`, возникает вопрос - что вы сэкономили, не дописав слово? Время, силы, вычислительные мощности? Зато людям теперь нужно думать, что это название означает. )  Называйте метод `get_neighbors_count` - и всем всё будет сразу понятно.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась добавлением двух массивов для созданных/удаленных клеток.

```
# Обновление игрового поля
def get_next_generation(cells: list) -> None:
    created = []
    deleted = []
    for cell in cells:
        neighbours = get_nei(cell, cells)
        if cell.life:
            if neighbours not in rules['survive']:
                created.append(cell)
        else:
            if neighbours in rules['born']:
                deleted.append(cell)
    for new_cell in created:
        new_cell.change()
    for old_cell in deleted:
        old_cell.change()
```